# Is there a way to concatenate a req.body requests?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

I have a list of items that I would like to iterate through, adding the value of i to each to find the next set of information.

Example: You can concatenate the string "req.body.item" + i + "Title" to get the result "req.body.item0Title"

But can you do that with the object req.body.item + i + Title? I keep getting "Title isn't defined or something similar.

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    console.log(req.body.item + i + Title);
}
```

Ideally, I'd love to see the console.log output to read the req.body reference  of, item0Title, item1Title, and item2Title.

Thanks team.

Comment: What exactly is `item`?  Is it an array?

Comment: `req.body[item + i + Title]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Comment: Currently, no. It's from a form with user input with three inputs. I'd like them to be in an array on completion of those three, and then inserted into another array with another twenty, but working through this in stages, since my last question became a wall of code and was rightfully ignored.

Comment: Kevin B - I get ReferenceError "Title is not defined".

Comment: Then why are you trying to add it to `i`? did you intend for it to be a string?

Comment: @Newsworthy put it in quotes, like this - `req.body[item + i + "Title"]`

Comment: I have a series of form inputs that follow the format of item1Title, item2Title, item3Title etc... and I can get the console.log of them with req.body.item1Title. I'm looking to iterate through a group of them, in this case with the i = 1-3 loop, without having to write it out three times. Is this possible?

Comment: Try `console.log(req.body.item + i + 'Title');` if you want `Title` as a string, although i don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: @dimitristseggenes OP wants to get the `item0Title` property of `req.body` without manually listing `item1Title` etc by hand. So they need what Kevin suggested, though he forgot the quotes around 'Title'.

Comment: @dimitristseggenes - I get NaNTitle on output three times.

Comment: @Al.G. - YES! That did it, apologies I was so confusing to everyone. I got it with console.log(req.body["item" + i + "Title"]);

Thanks dimitristseggenes and Kevin B as well. Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the cleanest way to do what you need.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    console.log(req.body[`item${i}Title`]);
}
```

**¿How does it work?**

*Objects are sometimes called associative arrays, since each property is associated with a string value that can be used to access it.*

Comment: That worked! Thank you, very helpful indeed. May I ask the significance of the $ sign? Does it indicate something unusual is coming next?

Comment: Single quotes (') and Double quotes (") they are used when working with strings, grave accent (\`) represent Template Strings, Template Strings can contain placeholders. These are indicated by the dollar sign and curly braces `(${expression})`. The expressions in the placeholders and the text between them get passed to a function. The default function just concatenates the parts into a single string, in this case we use it to be able to refer to the value of a variable and at the same time concatenate the string.

Comment: Thanks for the extra explanation @ccordon. Appreciated.